# Jquery EasyUI data grid save changes into database

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I am using jquery EasyUi data grid. As per documentation at http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid12.php

I have build up the datagrid. Now what I want is there is a function acceptchanges in datagrid I want to save all the table changes in one go. And I need it urgent wanted to deploy project by tomorrow. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var rows = $('#dg').datagrid('getRows');
$.each(rows, function(i, row) {
  $('#dg').datagrid('endEdit', i);
  var url = row.isNewRecord ? 'test.php?savetest=true' : 'test.php?updatetest=true';
  $.ajax(url, {
      type:'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:row
  });
});
```

Comment: You should add comments or an explanation to go with your solution

Answer (score 1):

You could simply update each row when user hits `save`. Within the function `saverow(target)` in demo, `target` is the save link so you can get the row using:

```
function saverow(target){

    var $row=$(target).closest('tr');
    /* map text of each cell to an array*/
    var cellData= $row.find('td').map(function(){
         return $(this).text();
    }).get();

     /* send array to server*/

    $.post('upDateUrl', { rowData : cellData}, function(response){
         /* do something with response*/
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But the problem is I want to do is batch update, I will make changes and then in the end want to save all row that I have edited. Can you help me in this